# Spring Security configuration and Angular login problem

Tags: angular, spring-security

I'm new to spring mvc and angular, and currently building a project using spring mvc as REST api, angular as frontend. The problem is I configured spring security, and trying to login by sending post request to backend. But it keeps showing the following error:

```
09-Apr-2020 22:49:11.124 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping for OPTIONS /BackEnd_war_exploded/loginAction
```

Here is the WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.neu.finalpro.controller" })
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
WebConfig.java

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/").suffix(".jsp");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter xmlMessageConverter() {
        return new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(jsonMessageConverter());
        converters.add(xmlMessageConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Here are some files in frontend
auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

interface AuthResponseData {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  email: string;
  recovemail: string;
  phone: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  signup(username: string, password: string, email: string, recovemail: string, phone: string, role: string) {

    const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('username',username)
    .set('password', password)
    .set('email', email)
    .set('recovemail', recovemail)
    .set('phone', phone)
    .set('role', role)

    console.log(params);

    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/BackEnd_war_exploded/signup", {params: params});
  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {

    const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('username', username)
    .set('password', password);

    const header = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Accept', '*/*')
    .set('User-Agent', 'PostmanRuntime/7.24.1')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    console.log(params);

    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/BackEnd_war_exploded/loginAction", {headers: header, params: params});
  }

  getUser(username: string) {

    const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('username', username);

    return this.http.get<AuthResponseData>("http://localhost:8080/BackEnd_war_exploded/getuser", {params: params});
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not of course full solution, by providing `.formLogin().loginPage("/login")` you tell spring security to redirect to /login, but you have REST so `loginPage("/login")`  should not be there. Having `.loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction")` is fine, this will set `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`'s processing url and it will not hit Spring MVC or controller but from angular you make post request like you would request controller endpoint, so you get that exception.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to remove loginPage("/login"). It doesn't work, but it could be successfully authenticated if I send post request to "/loginAction" using postman.

Comment: you also need custom authenticationenetrypoint which will send your angular app 401 unauthroized response if not authenticated for the app to show login page see here adn register it to httpsecurity: https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-mvc-test-examples/blob/master/spring-32/src/main/java/net/petrikainulainen/spring/testmvc/security/authentication/RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.java. Also read about proxy settings for your angular app: https://sudhasoftjava.wordpress.com/2018/10/05/proxy-configuration-in-angular/.